# Adding multiple event type to same kafka topic in .net

Tags: c#, .net, avro

I am trying to add multiple schemas to the same subject in the schema registry, so I have set **ValueSubjectNameStrategy** to **SubjectNameStrategy.TopicRecord**, also set the register automatically to **AutomaticRegistrationBehavior.Always**. But while auto registering the schema it still using the SubjectNameStrategy.Topic strategy.

```
 var schemaRegistryConfig = new SchemaRegistryConfig { Url = "http://localhost:8081", ValueSubjectNameStrategy = SubjectNameStrategy.TopicRecord };
        var registry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryConfig);
        var builder = new ProducerBuilder<string, SplitLineKGN>(KafkaConfig.Producer.GetConfig(_config.GetSection("KafkaProducer")))
                    .SetAvroValueSerializer(registry, registerAutomatically: AutomaticRegistrationBehavior.Always)
                    .SetErrorHandler((_, error) => Console.Error.WriteLine(error.ToString()));
        _producerMsg = builder.Build();
await _producerMsg.ProduceAsync("MyTopic", new Message<string, SampleMessage> { Key = key, Value = line });
```

how to auto register multiple schemas to a topic?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that you changed a [subject naming strategy for a topic](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema-validation.html#id1)
2. **SchemaRegistryConfig.ValueSubjectNameStrategy** is deprecated, it should now be configured using the serializer's configuration: [code](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.SchemaRegistry/SchemaRegistryConfig.cs#L81)
3. For producing multiple event types with a **single producer** you have to use **AvroSerializer<ISpecificRecord>** as described below:

   ```
   var schemaRegistryConfig = new SchemaRegistryConfig { Url = "http://localhost:8081" };

   using var schemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryConfig);

   var avroSerializerConfig = new AvroSerializerConfig
   {
       SubjectNameStrategy = SubjectNameStrategy.TopicRecord,
       AutoRegisterSchemas = true // (the default)
   };

   // Assuming this is your own custom code because the Confluent 
   // producer doesn't have anything like this.
   var producerConfig = KafkaConfig.Producer.GetConfig(_config.GetSection("KafkaProducer"));

   using var producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, ISpecificRecord>(producerConfig)
           .SetValueSerializer(new AvroSerializer<ISpecificRecord>(schemaRegistryClient, avroSerializerConfig))
           .SetErrorHandler((_, error) => Console.Error.WriteLine(error))
           .Build();

   var deliveryResult = await producer.ProduceAsync("MyTopic", new Message<string, ISpecificRecord> 
   { 
       Key = key, 
       Value = line 
   });

   Console.WriteLine($"Delivered to: {deliveryResult.TopicPartitionOffset}");
   ```